# Show that the set is convex

Tags: general-topology

A set $Z$ is *convex* when $z_1,z_2 \in Z\Rightarrow (1-h)z_1+hz_2\in Z$ for all $h\in [0,1]$.

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are convex than $X*Y=\{(1-t)x+ty\;|\;x\in X,y\in Y, t\in [0,1]\}$ is convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof seems to be straightforward. Let $x_1,x_2$ be arbitrary elements of $X$, $y_1,y_2$ be arbitrary elements of $Y$, and $h\in[0,1]$  be an arbitrary number. Then

$$((1-t_1)x_1+t_1y_1)(1-h)+((1-t_2)x_2+t_2y_2)h=$$
$$(1-t_1)(1-h)x_1+(1-t_2)hx_2+t_1(1-h)y_1+t_2hy_2=$$
$$((1-t_1)(1-h)+(1-t_2)h)x+(t_1(1-h)+t_2h)y$$ for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.
Since $((1-t_1)(1-h)+(1-t_2)h)+(t_1(1-h)+t_2h)=1$, we see
that $((1-t_1)(1-h)+(1-t_2)h)x+(t_1(1-h)y+t_2h)y\in Z$.